# <!--nextpage--> and previews

Tags: previews, nextpage

I am trying to preview my blog post that has `<!--nextpage-->` but clicking on any of the other pages just brings back to the home page.

There was an old thread that never got resolved 4 years ago https://wordpress.org/support/topic/nextpage-doesnt-work-on-preview?replies=3

The URL when I do a preview looks like this

`https://www.trajano.net/?p=1569&preview_id=1569&preview_nonce=c1ab9c2efc&post_format=standard&_thumbnail_id=-1&preview=true`

All well and good, but once I click on a page this happens:

`https://www.trajano.net/?p=1569%2F2%2F&preview_id=1569&preview_nonce=c1ab9c2efc&preview=true`

Note that the page number gets injected after `?p=1569` like `?p=1569/2/&preview...` if it was decoded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a bug regarding *content pagination* links not working when previewing *scheduled* posts or pages.

See ticket [#32295](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/32295)

There's already a proposed patch that adds the missing `future` status check within the `_wp_link_page()` helper function, that generates the content pagination links.

We could e.g. construct a quick-fix like:

```
add_filter( 'preview_post_link', function( $link, $post )
{
    if( ! is_admin() && is_preview() && 'future' === get_post_status( $post ) )
        $link = preg_replace( '~p=(\d+)%2F(\d+)%2F~', 'p=$1&page=$2', $link );

    return $link;
}, 10, 2 );
```

or use the `wp_link_pages_link` filter:

```
add_filter( 'wp_link_pages_link', function( $link, $i )
{
    if( $i > 1 && 'future' === get_post_status( get_the_ID() ) && is_preview() )
            $link = preg_replace( '~p=(\d+)%2F(\d+)%2F~', 'p=$1&page=$2', $link );

    return $link;
}, 10, 2 );
```